Why does postman not encode + in query params but insomnia does?
For some reason Postman is encoding most of the query string for this URL except the +
http://localhost:3001/demo?asAt=2024-12-09T14:00:00+00:00
in postman becomes
http://localhost:3001/demo?asAt=2024-12-09T14%3A00%3A00+00%3A00
Whereas for the same URL in insomnia it encodes + to %2B.
http://localhost:3001/demo?asAt=2024-12-09T14%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00
Why might this be?
